# Excel with Legacy (Web) connection - prompted for login on every refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel, apache-http-server

(I am the author of both the Excel sheet and the webpage the connection goes to)

I have an Excel sheet with multiple embedded Connections: "From Web (Legacy)" to a webpage with an HTML table in it. The web page is protected with HTTP Basic Authentication.

When changing the password on the web page and subsequent refresh off, Excel pops up the dialogue correctly and only once, even if there are multiple connections.

The dialogue also pops up when closing and re-opening the Excel file and subsequent refresh, however it does this even when the login information is not changed and the "Remember my credentials" tickbox is ticked. The password is also retained correctly.

[image]

For ease of use, I would like the dialogue not to appear, if the password has not changed. Is this possible, I'm happy to look at solutions including a connection file, Macros or VBA code

I do also studiously press Save when prompted if I want to save changes after a refresh, however ideally, this would not be necessary either.

Comment: How about using Power Query to get data from Web?

Comment: @Lee, would appreciate any pointers, not my core expertise

Comment: @Lee from my research into PowerQuery, I am already using it when creating the connection. There don't seem to be any additional options in PowerQuery that are not in the normal connection dialogue.

Comment: Try: (1) To add in `web.config` the lines: `<add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />` and `<add verb="PROPFIND" allowed="false" />`, (2) To change in the web server the HTTP Authentication to use NTLM.

Comment: @harrymc im limited to basic auth on an apache server

Comment: This changes everything. Try on the client side to add the site to the Trusted Sites zone in *Control Panel > Internet Options > Security > Trusted sites > Sites > Add* and uncheck "Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone".

Comment: Hi @harrymc, ok, thats not something my users will be able to. But it is on https already

Comment: I thought you wrote HTTP. In any case, you can do the same via the registry, so by distributing a `.reg` file. See [article](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2012/07/how-to-configuring-ie-site-zone-mapping-using-group-policy-without-locking-out-the-user/).

Comment: @harrymc, yes, I meant HTTP in the context of HTTP basic authentication. The Excel sheet is distributed into very corporate environments, which will not allow to change local settings.

Comment: Given these limitations, I cannot think of any other solution than removing the password requirement from the webpage. Some other safeguards can be added, for example checking the originating IP address.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc for your efforts. So far I think the popup will survive the customer test, as having the data auto update is hopefully enough benefit in itself. I was hoping it could be controlled by VBA or macro, but maybe not. As I understand your comments, the popup would not appear if NTLM auth was used? If this approach causes too much friction, I will investigate implementing this instead

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions which are said to help in such a case, but are only meaningful
in the context of a Windows server using IIS:

- To add in the web application for the `web.config` file the lines:

  ```
  <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
  <add verb="PROPFIND" allowed="false" />
  ```
- To change for the website in IIS the HTTP Authentication method to using NTLM.

When using Apache these suggestions do not apply, so you might be better off by
removing the password requirement from the webpage.

For security you may add some other safeguards.
For example, you could check if the originating IP address is coming from a
source that is authorized to use the web-page.

Comment: This gave me another idea. My login is actually handled by a Symfony application, so I can response to the OPTION and PROPFIND requests as I wish. Is there documentation (or knowledge) how IIS responds to these requests when your configuration is set like this? If not, will investigate myself with a proxy.

Comment: If used with IIS server and NTLM Authentication, normally the client will cache the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting from Excel, you could export the table in Excel format from the webpage.

There are many ways to do this.

Here is an example:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: Thank you. The purpose of the system is to distribute updates of the data modelled in Excel without having to manage files and having to know what is the latest. The web based database manages this for the users

Comment: Sounds like a job for MS-Access or other database engine. What you are trying to do is way harder than using tools made for purpose.

Comment: If you want it to be a web page you can publish Access to Sharepoint and then pull data in to Excel using native DB calls. Excel and Access were designed to work together this way.

Comment: I don't think the multi tenanted security model we need as well as the data warehouse behind it makes Access a good candidate for this. Sorry I minimised my question to the essence of the problem. I find it frustrating that the behaviour of different data adapters is different, it is the way Microsoft operated in the 90ties and noughties, but we can likely lhve with the restrictions. Note that with this solution we can place the user interface into any company without having to interact with It, nor having to install anything, nor having to build a rich Web client